# Django update method for incrementing in jsonfields is super slow

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a model using json fields, while this works like a charm 99% of times I now have a kinda annoying issue, execution time.

I need to increment a LOT of records using Django's ORM `update` method, I don't know how fast it should be if the db was using something else than json fields, but basically here's some examples of time I'm facing:

- 4000 records update for just a +1 in a json field took 20 seconds
- 6000 records update took almost 2 minutes

Those were small ones, I expect some update to have more than 100000 records, could even reach a million.

For the technical side of what I am exactly doing:

I use `filter` on a range inside the jsonfield values to extract records that requires an update, this runs perfectly fine, after getting the queryset I use `update` to increment one of the jsonfield value by 1.

This behavior is very specific and probably not the most optimal but this is what I have for now, to do it I make a raw sql query using `RawSQL`, for reference here is the function that generate the said query:

```py
def jsonfield_increment(field_name: str, key: str, increment_by: int = 1, operator: str = "+") -> RawSQL:
    sql = f"""
        jsonb_set(
            {field_name},
            '{{{key}}}',
            (COALESCE({field_name}->>'{key}','12')::int {operator} {increment_by})::text::jsonb
        )
    """

    return RawSQL(sql, [])
```

This method basically extract the value of `key` inside `field` and then increment it.

Then I just run the `update` method on the queryset I filtered before with `field=jsonfield_increment(args)`.

So here's what I'm wondering,

- Is there a way to optimize how I update records ? This update needs to run quite oftenly.
- Should I split the update on each X record in the queryset and save each chunk using a thread pool ?
- Should I use another method than `update` and store instances and then use `bulk_update`?
- Should I take time to completely rework how those ints are stored and not use jsonfield ?

While the last one sounds like the best option, I am a bit scared of doing it
as what I store there is a bit dynamic so it would require a whole
new table with relations, and it could end up with more than 100
millons records with like `name`, `int`, `data` (mandatory jsonfield) and `parent` where parent would
be the object that currently store the ints. Indexes could make it fast but then writting on that table could take some time.

I can try to provide the SQL generated by the `update` method if that can help.

Comment: because a 6000 record update does not take 30sec you have some N^2 problem, most likely the `filter`, is it some generator

Comment: Are you doing these one row at a time or the whole batch in one statement? If one row at a time, stop doing that - the whole point of a database is that it can do processing quite efficiently.

Comment: time how long it takes to do a NOP operation on the query elements for 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000 records

Comment: @rioV8: The `filter` looks like this: `Model.objects.filter(**{f"field__{dyn_key_name}__range": interval})` , I could do timings, but I started on reworking the whole thing to not use jsonfield which seem more productive, kept old stuff in a branch in case

@RichardHuxton The whole point of the `update` method is to update everything in one statement

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to tell you what I would do. I have the json read from a pandas dataframe. The Pandas dataframe passes data to the Django ORM.
To pass data from Pandas to ORM I have 2 possible ways:
The best is to use sqlackemy, it is asynchronous, it lends itself perfectly to the work I need to do. I need to have an SSH connection with the host available. I need to configure sqlackemy in the setting.py.
The second use df.iterrows() to iterate the rows of the dataframe and with bulk_create() load them into the ORM model.
I didn't take into account that I had foreign keys in the ORM models. They slow down a lot with iteration.

Comment: DFs are used for the initial saving of all of those ints, however it doesn't really make sense to use one for the described behavior, what it does is increment a value in a jsonb by one on a set of records, loading all of those records as instances to load them in a DF to add +1 wouldn't really make sense especially since if you instancied the records you could simply iterate over them to directly edit the instance and bulk save them, which would do the same as using `update` which doesn't require the instancing

Comment: @Stephen Milic . I didn't understand your question at all. my apologies